# Confused between the usage of the sentence starting with Looking forward to

Tags: ing

Could anyone tell me which one is correct :

1) Looking forward to do more homework exercises with you in future

OR

2) Looking forward in doing more homework exercises with you in future

Since I am using `ing` with `look`, it seems more appropriate to used `doing` somewhere in the sentence later but in the first sentence, I have `to` and it doesn't sound appropriate to use `doing` after `to`. Please correct me if I am wrong. Thanks

Comment: ...looking forward to doing....http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/verb-patterns/look-forward-to

Comment: I think you've already answered your own question.  But I think I would change it to "Looking forward to completing more homework exercises with you in future"

Comment: *in the future* would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Cambridge link](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/it/grammatica/grammatica-britannico/verb-patterns/look-forward-to) supplied by Josh seems to provide the answer:

> The ‘to’ in look forward to is a preposition, so we must follow it by a noun phrase or a verb in the -ing form

Which gives:

> Looking forward *to doing* more homework exercises with you in  future.

Americans would most likely say *in the future*.